# Does this approach for factorizing RSA numbers help in any way?

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, cryptography, prime-factorization

I was thinking about why factorizing RSA numbers is so hard. When humans perform any kind of maths manually, they often employ various 'tricks' that get them closer to the answer. Some are based on mathematical facts, others are just instinctive approximations (such as square roots).

Don't such 'tricks' exist for factorization of a product of 2 large primes. For example, the first thing to do would be to figure out the possible last digits of the answer. We stick to decimal numbers, but a computer could do this in a number system of any base (even 999). Based on previous numbers, can an algorithm be written to 'predict' the factorization based on the individual digits in various number systems.

Comment: None of these tricks are going to be enough help in factoring the 300-1000 digit numbers that are used in the RSA algorithm in practice.  Okay, you have narrowed down the last digit of the factors.  What about the other 499 digits?

Comment: @MJD Can't an algorithm solve digits from right to left, first the ones place, then the tens (since it knows what the ones digits are, or could be), then hundreds and so on?

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind, exactly, so I suggest that you show me with an example. Please tell me how you use these tricks to factor the very small number 59447933. Now the two factors evidently end with either 1 and 3 or with 7 and 9.  Which is it?  And what do you do about the ten's places?

Comment: Changing $n$ to base $b$ is actually harder than dividing $n/b$.  Thus, instead of changing to a whole bunch of other bases for nice divisibility rules, you might as well perform trial division.  But trial division is too slow, so...

Comment: I do not understand why this question, which is certainly on-topic, and which is seemingly asked in good faith, and unlike many questions on this site, does not appear to be an attempt to cheat on a homework assignment, is being downvoted.

Comment: @MJD Knowing that last digits are 1,3 or 7,9 , we can write down cases like _______01 x _______03 , _______11 x _______03 , ________21 x _______01, and so on, giving us 200 cases, of which only a certain number would work. Then we can write down the 10x10=100 cases for the third digit (hundreds), for each of the valid cases found so far.

Comment: This method may not be of any use, I'm just asking if it is.

Comment: I  invite you to give it a try and see for yourself how well it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it most likely doesn't, as stated by others in comments.